# phpの配列でidが同じ物をカテゴリー分けして出力したい

Tags: php, mysql

以下のようにprojectテーブルとclientテーブルがDBに存在し、LEFT JOINで結合した結果をclient.id順にソートして取得するとします。

```
mysql> SELECT p.id, p.project_name, p.client_id, c.client_name FROM project p LEFT JOIN client c ON p.client_id = c.id WHERE p.active_flag = '1' ORDER BY c.id DESC ;
```

取得結果

```
+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
| id  | project_name                                                 | client_id | client_name |
+-----+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------+-------------+
|  50 | Aリスト                                           　　　　　　　　|         9 | admin       |
| 188 | Bリスト                                                        |         9 | admin       |
|   7 | Cリスト                                                        |         2 | user      |
|   8 | Dリスト                                                        |         2 | user      |
```

上記の結果をclient_name毎にカテゴリー分けして出力するにはどの様な方法があるのでしょうか？

出力としては以下の様なHTMLにしたいと考えています。

- admin

  - Aリスト
  - Bリスト
- user

  - Cリスト
  - Dリスト

ご教示いただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/68630

Comment: @kphex マルチポスト先などSO以外で解決した場合、解決した内容を自己回答し承認してください。

Answer (score 1):

まず、PHP側でデータベースからデータを取得するには、PDOを使うのが一般的です。PDOを用いてSQL文を実行し、データを取得するには以下のようにします。

```
//データベースへ接続する。
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=yourdbname;host=yourhost';
$user = 'youruser';
$password = 'yourpass';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

// SQL文を実行する。
$sql = "SELECT p.id, p.project_name, p.client_id, c.client_name 
        FROM project p LEFT JOIN client c ON p.client_id = c.id 
        WHERE p.active_flag = '1' 
        ORDER BY c.id DESC";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

//SQL文で指定したすべてのデータを取得する。
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
```

DBから取得後のデータをclient_nameごとに出力するのであれば、client_nameをキーとした配列を作成しましょう。

```
//データをclient_id,project_idごとに配列へ格納する。
$data = array();
foreach($result as $project){
    $client_name = $project['client_name'];
    $project_id = $project['id'];
    $data[$client_name][$project_id] = $project;
}
```

あとは、HTMLへ表示するだけなので、$dataをforループを用いて出力するだけです。

```
print "<ul>";
foreach($data as $client_name => $projects){
    print "<li>{$client_name}";
    print "<ul>";        
    foreach($projects as $project){
        print "<li>{$project['project_name']}</li>";
    }
    print "</ul>";
}
print "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

多次元配列はどうでしょう

```
$a['client_name']['project_name']
```